# Why can't I choose a SVN repo for Jenkins SCM job?

Tags: jenkins, version-control

[image]

Noob question here, I'm trying to setup a Jenkins autobuild job for our project with SCM. However when I loaded Source Code Management it showed like the image instead of options to add Git or a local SVN. The "Add SCM" button had no function when I clicked on it.

Can you take a look to guide me if I missed anything or if there is any additional extension that I have to install?

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Is this a freestyle project? If so may be due to the Jenkins version you are seeing or maybe the plugins you have installed are different.

Comment: Yeah I'm choosing a freestyle prj, but the same happened when I choose a pipeline.
I think that's because of the plugins, but in the guides I found there's no mentioning the plugins that need installed.